# How do I create, and distinguish, global options using 'optparse-applicative'?

Tags: haskell, command-line-interface, optparse-applicative

In my Haskell executable, created using `optparse-applicative`, I would like to have a global option for `--version` alongside the global `--help` option that is available from all subcommands. However the [example provided](https://github.com/haskell-lang/haskell-lang/blob/master/static/tutorial/package-optparse-applicative.md#sub-commands-example) (see below) for adding a `--version` option to to a CLI with subcommands results in a `--version` option that is inconsistently available

```
$ cli create --version
Invalid option `--version'

Usage: cli create NAME
  Create a thing

$ cli delete --version
0.0
```

and never shows up in help for subcommands

```
$ cli create -h
Usage: cli create NAME
  Create a thing

Available options:
  NAME                     Name of the thing to create
  -h,--help                Show this help text

$ cli delete -h
Usage: cli delete 
  Delete the thing

Available options:
  -h,--help                Show this help text
```

The behavior I would like is for `--version` to be available globally and to all subcommands:

```
$ cli create -h
Usage: cli create NAME
  Create a thing

Available options:
  NAME                     Name of the thing to create
  --version                Show version
  -h,--help                Show this help text

$ cli delete -h
Usage: cli delete 
  Delete the thing

Available options:
  --version                Show version
  -h,--help                Show this help text

$ cli create --version
0.0

$ cli delete --version
0.0
```

It's not clear from the documentation how to achieve this.

In fact, I'd ideally like to be able to clearly group options in the help output:

```
$ cli create -h
Usage: cli create NAME
  Create a thing

Arguments:
  NAME                     Name of the thing to create

Global options:
  --version                Show version
  -h,--help                Show this help text

$ cli delete -h
Usage: cli delete 
  Delete the thing

Global options:
  --version                Show version
  -h,--help                Show this help text
```

Is there a way to achieve this using `optparse-applicative`?

---

```
{-#LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables#-}

import Data.Semigroup ((<>))
import Options.Applicative

data Opts = Opts
    { optGlobalFlag :: !Bool
    , optCommand :: !Command
    }

data Command
    = Create String
    | Delete

main :: IO ()
main = do
    (opts :: Opts) <- execParser optsParser
    case optCommand opts of
        Create name -> putStrLn ("Created the thing named " ++ name)
        Delete -> putStrLn "Deleted the thing!"
    putStrLn ("global flag: " ++ show (optGlobalFlag opts))
  where
    optsParser :: ParserInfo Opts
    optsParser =
        info
            (helper <*> versionOption <*> programOptions)
            (fullDesc <> progDesc "optparse subcommands example" <>
             header
                 "optparse-sub-example - a small example program for optparse-applicative with subcommands")
    versionOption :: Parser (a -> a)
    versionOption = infoOption "0.0" (long "version" <> help "Show version")
    programOptions :: Parser Opts
    programOptions =
        Opts <$> switch (long "global-flag" <> help "Set a global flag") <*>
        hsubparser (createCommand <> deleteCommand)
    createCommand :: Mod CommandFields Command
    createCommand =
        command
            "create"
            (info createOptions (progDesc "Create a thing"))
    createOptions :: Parser Command
    createOptions =
        Create <$>
        strArgument (metavar "NAME" <> help "Name of the thing to create")
    deleteCommand :: Mod CommandFields Command
    deleteCommand =
        command
            "delete"
            (info (pure Delete) (progDesc "Delete the thing"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, this (in particular, the categorized help text) isn't really easy to do with `optparse-applicative`, since it isn't quite the pattern that they were planning for with global arguments.  If you are okay with using `program --global-options command --local-options` (which is a fairly standard pattern) instead of `program command --global-and-local-options`, then you can use the approach shown in the linked example:

```
$ ./optparse-sub-example
optparse-sub-example - a small example program for optparse-applicative with
subcommands

Usage: optparse [--version] [--global-flag] COMMAND
  optparse subcommands example

Available options:
  -h,--help                Show this help text
  --version                Show version
  --global-flag            Set a global flag

Available commands:
  create                   Create a thing
  delete                   Delete the thing

$ ./optparse-sub-example --version create
0.0
$ ./optparse-sub-example --version delete
0.0
$ ./optparse-sub-example --global-flag create HI
Created the thing named HI
global flag: True
$ ./optparse-sub-example --global-flag delete
Deleted the thing!
global flag: True
```

(Note: I would advise going with this approach, since "global options before the command" is fairly standard).

If you also want the global options to be available in every subcommand, you will have a few issues.

1. As far as I know, there is no way to affect the help text output in order to group them separately inside the individual command help texts.
2. You will need some custom `subparser`-like function that adds your global options & merges them with any global options before the command.

For #2, one way to restructure the example to support this might be something along these lines:

To start with, standard boilerplate and imports:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ApplicativeDo #-}

import Data.Monoid
import Data.Semigroup ((<>))
import Options.Applicative
import Options.Applicative.Types
```

`Opts` are explicitly split into `optGlobals` and `optCommand`, making it easy to deal with all of the global options at once if more are available:

```
data Opts = Opts
    { optGlobals :: !GlobalOpts 
    , optCommand :: !Command
    }
data GlobalOpts = GlobalOpts { optGlobalFlag :: Bool }
```

`GlobalOpts` should be a `Semigroup` and a `Monoid`, since we need to merge options seen at various different points (before the command, after the command, etc.). It should also be possible, with suitable alterations to `mysubparser` below, to require global options to be given only after commands and omit this requirement.

```
instance Semigroup GlobalOpts where
  -- Code for merging option parser results from the multiple parsers run
  -- at various different places. Note that this may be run with the default
  -- values returned by one parser (from a location with no options present)
  -- and the true option values from another, so it may be important
  -- to distinguish between "the default value" and "no option" (since "no
  -- option" shouldn't override another value provided earlier, while
  -- "user-supplied value that happens to match the default" probably should).
  --
  -- In this case this doesn't matter, since the flag being provided anywhere
  -- should be enough for it to be considered true.
  (GlobalOpts f1) <> (GlobalOpts f2) = GlobalOpts (f1 || f2)
instance Monoid GlobalOpts where
  -- Default values for the various options. These should probably match the
  -- defaults used in the option declarations.
  mempty = GlobalOpts False
```

As before, a `Command` type to represent the different possible commands:

```
data Command
    = Create String
    | Delete
```

The real magic: `mysubparser` wraps `hsubparser` to add global options and deal with merging them. It takes the parser for global options as an argument:

```
mysubparser :: forall a b. Monoid a
            => Parser a
            -> Mod CommandFields b
            -> Parser (a, b)
mysubparser globals cmds = do
```

To start with, it runs the global parser (to catch any globals given before a command):

```
  g1 <- globals
```

It then uses `hsubparser` to get a command parser, and modifies it to also parse global options:

```
  (g2, r) <- addGlobals $ hsubparser cmds
```

Finally, it merges the two global option sets, and returns the parsed global options and the command parser result:

```
  pure (g1 <> g2, r)
  where
```

The `addGlobals` helper function:

```
        addGlobals :: forall c. Parser c -> Parser (a, c)
```

If `NilP` was given, we just use `mempty` to get the default option set:

```
        addGlobals (NilP x) = NilP $ (mempty,) <$> x
```

The important case: if we have an `OptP` around an `Option` that uses a `CommandReader`, the `globals` parser is added to every command parser:

```
        addGlobals (OptP (Option (CmdReader n cs g) ps)) =
          OptP (Option (CmdReader n cs $ fmap go . g) ps)
          where go pi = pi { infoParser = (,) <$> globals <*> infoParser pi }
```

In all other cases, either just use the default option set, or merge option sets from recursive `Parser`s as appropriate:

```
        addGlobals (OptP o) = OptP ((mempty,) <$> o)
        addGlobals (AltP p1 p2) = AltP (addGlobals p1) (addGlobals p2)
        addGlobals (MultP p1 p2) =
          MultP ((\(g2, f) -> \(g1, x) -> (g1 <> g2, f x)) <$> addGlobals p1)
                (addGlobals p2)
        addGlobals (BindP p k) = BindP (addGlobals p) $ \(g1, x) ->
                                   BindP (addGlobals $ k x) $ \(g2, x') ->
                                     pure (g1 <> g2, x')
```

Modifications to the `main` function are fairly minimal, and mostly related to using the new `GlobalOpts`.  Once a parser for `GlobalOpts` is available, passing it to `mysubparser` is quite easy:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    (opts :: Opts) <- execParser optsParser
    case optCommand opts of
        Create name -> putStrLn ("Created the thing named " ++ name)
        Delete -> putStrLn "Deleted the thing!"
    putStrLn ("global flag: " ++ show (optGlobalFlag (optGlobals opts)))
  where
    optsParser :: ParserInfo Opts
    optsParser =
        info
            (helper <*> programOptions)
            (fullDesc <> progDesc "optparse subcommands example" <>
             header
                 "optparse-sub-example - a small example program for optparse-applicative with subcommands")
    versionOption :: Parser (a -> a)
    versionOption = infoOption "0.0" (long "version" <> help "Show version")
    globalOpts :: Parser GlobalOpts
    globalOpts = versionOption <*>
      (GlobalOpts <$> switch (long "global-flag" <> help "Set a global flag"))
    programOptions :: Parser Opts
    programOptions =
      uncurry Opts <$> mysubparser globalOpts (createCommand <> deleteCommand)
    createCommand :: Mod CommandFields Command
    createCommand =
        command
            "create"
            (info createOptions (progDesc "Create a thing"))
    createOptions :: Parser Command
    createOptions =
        Create <$>
        strArgument (metavar "NAME" <> help "Name of the thing to create")
    deleteCommand :: Mod CommandFields Command
    deleteCommand =
        command
            "delete"
            (info (pure Delete) (progDesc "Delete the thing"))
```

Notice that `mysubparser` should be a quite generic/reusable component.

This exhibits behavior closer to what you wanted:

```
$ ./optparse-sub-example create --global-flag HI
Created the thing named HI
global flag: True
$ ./optparse-sub-example --global-flag create HI
Created the thing named HI
global flag: True
$ ./optparse-sub-example --global-flag delete
Deleted the thing!
global flag: True
$ ./optparse-sub-example delete --global-flag
Deleted the thing!
global flag: True
$ ./optparse-sub-example delete
Deleted the thing!
global flag: False
$ ./optparse-sub-example delete --version
0.0
$ ./optparse-sub-example create --version
0.0
```

Comment: Ugh, so it looks like this isn't really possible. It's odd since the the package as provided (in the linked example) is inconsistent. The global `--help` option behaves in the way I'm looking for, but the global `--version` can't really be made to work the same way.

Comment: Even worse, the help for the subcommands doesn't list `--version` as a legal (global) option, even though it is.

Comment: @orome - `--help` is implemented the way that I have shown (the `h` in `hsubparser` is because it adds `--help`). `--help` is treated a bit different from other global options since it really has command-specific meaning. I did not show it in the example at the end, but if you use the `mysubparser` I have provide, `--version` will indeed appear in the subcommand help.

Comment: So it sounds like, without a lot of customizing work (which you've don here), it's not really possible.

Comment: I think that that's probably true. That said, the `mysubparser` here should be fairly re-usable (and isn't incredibly complex/hard-to-adapt), so if you really need this functionality for something, it may be useful/a possible avenue.